# Exchange service polls every minute and drains the battery

Tags: email, battery, exchange

Two days ago my Sony Xperia J phone's battery began to be drained very quickly. It seems, the Exchange service has gone mad (it uses 57% of the battery time). It polls constantly, I get a new mail every minute according to it (I have only 1 new mail actually). I already restarted the phone.
It even polls when it requests a security update.

What have gone wrong? Did Google release a new version of it?

Comment: No idea, but a request for clarification: Are you using an Exchange account with that device? That service indeed polls every minute, even with no account created. I simply disabled it, as I don't use Exchange at all. Solved it for me.

Comment: I do use this device, but it worked very well until now. What changed? I need to use it to get my workplace emails.

Comment: It gets even worse, it uses 64% now, and used up my 3G package as well.

Comment: If you can afford it: Try resetting the apps related to exchange (Exchange, plus maybe the Mail app used) by going to *Settings→Apps→Manage Apps*, force-closing the app, delete cache and data, reboot. You will then have to re-configure it, and if there were any local data they will be gone, but that might solve the issue. If your device is equipped with a custom recovery: boot into it, wipe cache and Dalvik. Nothing lost that way, but that solved some mysterious issues already in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to a 3rd party Exchange app and set the built-in Email application to Manual sync. It seems to work now.